# Distribute $n$ distinguishable balls into $k$ distinguishable baskets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a number $n$ and $k$ numbers $n_1,n_2,n_3\ldots, n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$n_1+n_2+n_3+\ldots+ n_k=n$
How many ways are there to distribute  distinguishable balls into $k$
distinguishable baskets so that exactly $n_i$ balls are placed in each basket $i$ , $i =1,2,\ldots, k$?

Also, how many ways are there to distribute $n$ distinguishable balls into $k$
distinguishable baskets? Let's say if there is no restriction to the number of balls in each basket.

I can't really understand the logic of that. I mean, there are $n$ balls by the given forumla $n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k=n$ and there are $k$ baskets? So what's the deal with "$n_1, n_2,\dots$ etc."? Why isn't it $x_1,x_2,\dots$ etc.?
How do you think should I do it?

I mean if they were identical balls I would use the $k+n-1\choose{n-1}$ formula.
But here they are different.

I can't really figure out what should I do in both of those questions.
Thanks.

For the second answer it's gonna be $k^n$?

($k$: number of baskets; $n$: number of balls)

---

Edit: The bins are not identical. I thought about it, and if $n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots,n_k$ are simply numbers which represent the amount of balls in each bin (for example $n_1$ balls in bin number $1$, $n_2$ balls in bin number $2$ and so on), then there is only one option, right? Because we already have the exact amount of balls in each basket.

But maybe it's something fishy because we can find a lot of options for $n_1+n_2+...+n_k=n$ ...
I mean, $n_1$ can be different in each option...

Comment: Have a look at https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-identical-bins

Comment: Hey but they are not identical (the bins). I thought about it, and if n1,n2,n3..nk are simply numbers which represent the amount of balls in each bin (for example n1 balls in bin number 1, n2 balls in bin number 2 and so on) so there is only 1 option , right? because we already have the exact amount of balls.

Comment: Oh sorry, you can search for distinct objects into distinct bins, on brilliant. My bad.

Comment: Here you are: https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-distinct-bins/

Comment: It seems that you know the answer $k^n$, don't you?

Comment: @user yes but as someone said here I can't leave a bin empty, and moreover, the bins has to include the exact number of balls  that is specified in the ni.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- So what is your suggetion so solve this? What happens if  there is no restriction to the number of balls in each basket? does it change something?

Comment: Not very good at combinatorics, still learning. I think it will be ${n \choose 1} + {{n-1} \choose 2 } $ and so on till k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the number of ways of distributing $n$ distinguishable balls to $k$ distinguishable bins without restriction is $k^n$ since there are $k$ choices for each of the $n$ balls.

As for the number of ways of distributing $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k$ balls to $k$ distinguishable baskets so that exactly $n_i$ balls are placed in basket $i$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, select which $n_1$ of the $n$ balls are placed in the first basket, which $n_2$ of the remaining $n - n_1$ balls are placed in the second basket, which $n_3$ of the remaining $n - n_1 - n_2$ balls are placed in the third basket, and so forth until you are left with $n_k$ balls to choose from the remaining $n - n_1 - n_2 - \cdots - n_{k - 1}$ to place in the $k$th basket.  This can be done in
$$\binom{n}{n_1}\binom{n - n_1}{n_2}\binom{n - n_1 - n_2}{n_3} \cdots \binom{n - n_1 - n_2 - \cdots - n_{k - 1}}{n_k}$$
ways.  Let's simplify the above expression.
\begin{align*}
& \binom{n}{n_1}\binom{n - n_1}{n_2}\binom{n - n_1 - n_2}{n_3} \cdots \binom{n - n_1 - n_2 - \cdots - n_{k - 1}}{n_k}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!(n - n_1)!} \cdot \frac{(n - n_1)!}{n_2!(n - n_1 - n_2)!} \cdot \frac{(n - n_1 - n_2)!}{n_3!(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3)!} \cdots \frac{(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1})!}{n_k!(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1} - n_k)!}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1} - n_k)!}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!0!}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!}
\end{align*}
where we have used the fact that $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k$ in the penultimate line.

Why does this answer make sense?

Imagine lining up all $n$ balls in some order.  We can do this in $n!$ ways.  Place the first $n_1$ balls in the first box, the next $n_2$ balls in the second box, the next $n_3$ balls in the third box, and so forth until we place the last $n_k$ balls in the $k$th box.  The factors in the denominator represent the number of orders in which the same $n_i$ balls could be placed in the $i$th box without changing the distribution.

**Addendum:**  If we impose the additional requirement that there must be at least one ball in each basket, then we must subtract those distributions which leave one or more of the baskets empty.

There are $\binom{k}{j}$ ways to exclude $j$ of the baskets from receiving a ball and $(k - j)^n$ ways to distribute the $n$ balls to the remaining $k - j$ baskets.  Thus, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways of distributing $n$ distinguishable balls to $k$ distinguishable baskets so that no basket is left empty is
$$\prod_{j = 1}^{k} (-1)^{j} \binom{k}{j}(k - j)^n$$
This is also the number of surjective functions from a set with $n$ elements to a set with $k$ elements.

Comment: Could you tell why it is multiplied and not added?

Comment: in the beginning you told me I was right about k^n but you totally ignored that in your answer, can you explain why? And what happens if there is no restriction to the number of balls in each basket? does it change something? because @UmbQbify-Key20- gave me the following answer (nchoose1)+(n−1choose2)  and so on till k, but it seems identical to your answer here.

Comment: If one task can be performed in $m$ ways and a second task can be performed in $n$ ways independently of how the first task is performed, the two tasks can be performed in $mn$ ways.  This is called the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  If one task can be performed in $m$ ways and another task which cannot be performed at the same time can be performed in $n$ ways, the number of ways of performing one of the tasks is $m + n$.  This is called the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).

Comment: @BenTyler When there are no restrictions on the number of balls placed in each basket, you have $k$ choices for each of the $n$ balls.  Hence, there are indeed $$\underbrace{k \cdot k \cdot k \cdots k}_{n~\text{factors}} = k^n$$ possible distributions of $n$ distinguishable balls to $k$ distinguishable baskets.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, but k^n indeed includes empty baskets which doesn't possible here because n1,n2,n...k are numbers and not 0.

Comment: @BenTyler  There are two separate questions.  The second one says that there are no restrictions on the number of balls in each basket, which allows for the possibility that there are no balls in a basket.  If we imposed the restriction that there must be at least one ball in each basket, we would be counting the number of surjective functions from a set of $n$ elements to a set of $k$ elements.  To do so, we would use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I agree that the second question includes ALL possibilities, but the question also says that n1,n2,n3…,nk∈N which means no one of them can be 0, right? And if you suggest to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, it stays 100% the same as the first answer? so I think it's weird that both question have the same answer

Comment: I provided an addendum to my answer to discuss what happens if we impose the additional requirement that at least one ball be placed in each basket.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to distribute $n$ distinct objects in $k$ distinct baskets so that there are exactly $n_i$ objects in $i$-th basket ($\sum_i n_i=n$) is
$$
\frac{n!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^kn_i!}.
$$

Comment: Isn't this for identical objects? Also, isn't this should be just s comment?

Comment: I think this is for identical objects and here the balls are different. I thought about placing all the n1,n2...nk objects in a random order so that I use k!, and then maybe do something with that..

Comment: @BenTyler  The formula provided in this answer is correct.  Notice that it is simply a compact form of the answer I provided.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes but you also say this is the answer for both of the question.. and I can't understand why.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- No, the formula is correct. Why should it be a comment?